# Git - remote: error: cannot run hooks/post-receive: No such file or directory

Tags: git

I get the error :

```
remote: error: cannot run hooks/post-receive: No such file or directory
```

When trying to push to remote. The post-receivce file exists in the correct location (testnew.git/hooks) and contains:

```
#!/bin/bash2
export GIT_DIR=/var/www/testnew/testnew/.git/
export GIT_WORK_TREE=/var/www/testnew/testnew/
cd /var/www/testnew/testnew/

echo "here we go..."
git fetch
git merge origin/master
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

I've tried setting permissions on post-receive using:

```
chmod a+x post-receive
```

But this gives same error. 
Setting permission to 755 removes the error , but the script does'nt run.

Comment: what happens when you run directly from your shell hooks/post-receive?
My guess is that /bin/bash2 does not exist, at least its not an usual interpreter, /bin/bash should be sufficient

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This would happen if the `hooks/post-receive` file exists, is marked executable, but cannot be executed. It cannot be executed, because the interpreter, `/bin/bash2`, either does not exist or is not executable.

Replace the `/bin/bash2` with name of bash that does exist and is executable on the server.

(The reason the error looks like this is, that the operating system only returns the error status, "No such file or directory", but does not report which file does not exist. And the code that tried to execute it does not know that the system already read `hooks/post-receive` and was looking for `/bin/bash2`. All it knows is it tried to run `hooks/post-receive`, so that's what it prints).

Comment: This was the issue. Switching to /bin/bash worked fine. Thanks.

Comment: For anyone wondering, you can run `which bash` to find the path of currently available bash.

Answer (score 23):

In addition (for future reference and documentation on this question) if you were to run `echo $SHELL` in your shell you should see an expected result, in this case *(based on the approved answer)* you would expect `/bin/bash` as your result. But **another possible problem can be an unseen carriage return**.

Try running `hooks/post-receive` if you're still having issues, you may get a response like this:

```
-bash: hooks/post-receive: /bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

The key here is the `^M` that is **proof that you are in fact getting an unexpected carriage return**, otherwise if it had worked you would probably get a hanging response.

Fix that and it should fix your problem. The way to do that, use `dos2unix`, for example:

```
dos2unix .htaccess
```

Comment: Adding to this answer, if you are using Sublime Text, you can got to View -> Line Endings -> Unix.  Select Unix and then save the file again.

Comment: Adding to this answer, use `find ./ -type f -exec dos2unix {} \;` to convert line-endlings for all files in a current directory.

Comment: This was the answer for me. Running the hooks/pre-commit (using pre-commit in my particular case) confirmed that I had a bad character in this script from a fellow developer that uses Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have the the correct 775 permissions.

For me it worked by redoing the folder structure with

```
git init --bare
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had VSCode's `End of line sequence` set to `CRLF`. Setting it to `LF` and resaving the git hook worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

It was caused by me forgetting to do `git init` first.

Answer (score 0):

Though this question was asked several years ago, but I felt I could add my solution for future readers.
In my own case, the following steps solved it:

- I was sure that I had done `git init --bare`
- from my bash console, I ran `which bash`, then I saw that `#!/bin/bash` was sufficient
- from a bash console, knowing fully well that I am in my bare-repos app folder (equivalent of `~/bare-repos/mysite.git`, I ran `hooks/post-receive` to see if this work well. In my own case, I got `bash: hooks/post-receive: /bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`
- Then, I knew that I was suffering from an unexpected carriage return, but I don't want to use `dos2unix` in pythonanywhere.
- I opened the post-receive file in pythonanywhere's editor, cleared all the lines, and manually keyed-in the line as opposed to copying and pasting the lines.
- Again, from a bash console, knowing fully well that I am in my bare-repo app folder (equivalent of `~/bare-repos/mysite.git`, I ran hooks/post-receive to see if this work well. In my own case, No error was thrown.
- I was good to go.