# cannot run hooks/post-update: No such file or directory

Tags: git, bash

Thx to this http://danbarber.me/using-git-for-deployment/ great article I managed to have a remote server under git control.

Unfortunatly I had to change server.

Now after finishing all steps in the tutorial and running

```
git push origin master
```

I get:

```
error: cannot run hooks/post-update: No such file or directory
To root@myproject.com:../var/git/myproject.git
```

I 've tried many times and variations. I replaced

```
#!/bin/sh
```

for

```
#!/bin/bash
```

after reading [Git - remote: error: cannot run hooks/post-receive: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11630433/git-remote-error-cannot-run-hooks-post-receive-no-such-file-or-directory)

Anyway as far as I checked ( multiple times ) the paths are correct.

I am wondering why it says :../var instead of :/var but I do not have any idea where this comes from.

Any suggestions on how to make this work again?

Comment: Can you post output of `ls .git/hooks` and `cat .git/hooks/post-update`?

Comment: Run `ls -l .git/hooks` on the server. Make sure the `post-update` script is executable. Make sure the permissions on the `.git` and `.git/hooks` directories are correct as well.

Comment: Carriage return on the `#!` line? http://serverfault.com/questions/592702/no-such-file-or-directory-error-when-trying-to-execute-startup-script-in-debian

Comment: -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 217 Oct  8 14:18 post-update

Comment: no carriage return after #! in post-update

Comment: `#!/bin/bash`

`echo`
`echo "**** Pulling changes into Live [Hub's post-update hook]"`
`echo`

`cd /var/www/vhosts/myproject.com/httpdocs/app/ || exit`
`unset GIT_DIR`
`git pull hub master`

`exec git-update-server-info`

Comment: there is no post-update in .git/hooks/  there is none in the tutorial. I did however create a post-commit which is none essential says the tutorial. Here is it's content:  [root@vps-82455-2005 hooks]# cat post-commit
`#!/bin/bash`

`echo`
`echo "pushing changes to Hub [Live's post-commit hook]"`
`echo`

`git push hub`

Comment: some more permissions: `drwxr-xr-x 8 root root 4096 Oct  8 13:32 .git`
`drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Oct  8 13:57 hooks`

Comment: I just checked out the link by Wumpus and it turns out that there are carriage returns: ^M : tough lesson. So now I do not have any errors any more but changes are only updated to hub. Not to .git. I will investigate the cause for that later. (if someone might have a clue, I would love to hear) but for now many thx!   cat -v !!!

Answer (score 16):

If you have given 777 permissions and the issue still exists it is because there might be carriage returns(^M) in the script file, if you had copied the text from vim.

To view if this is the issue: `cat -v /path/file`
And if this is the issue you can simply solve it by `sed -i -e 's/\r//g' /path/file`

Comment: Please, what does the last command do ?

Comment: this is a stream editor command to make the changes quickly in case of big files

Answer (score 0):

../

means you are looking in the directory above where you presently are. You can see where you are currently with

pwd

so

error: cannot run hooks/post-update: No such file or directory
   To root@myproject.com:../var/git/myproject.git

means there is no file called myproject.git located there, perhaps you need to move that file up a directory.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes text editors enter non-ASCII characters in text. I had same problem so I created a new file with 'Notepad' and it solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

A little late for the original poster, but in case its helpful to anyone else who makes it to the thread as I did, EOL issues can also lead to this error. I scratched my head for a while trying to figure out why my hook wasn't working on the webserver, but did work on my local machine. Turned out to be that my server wanted LF and my machine was doing CRLF. Converted it and problem solved.