# GIT says "No such file or directory" but the file exists

Tags: git

Im facing this problem during GIT push:

```
git push production master

Enumerating objects: 11, done. Counting objects: 100% (11/11), done. Delta compression using up to 8 threads Compressing objects: 100% (6/6), done. Writing objects: 100% (6/6), 462 bytes | 462.00 KiB/s, done. Total 6 (delta 5), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0 remote: fatal: this operation must be run in a work tree To ssh://xx.xx.xx.xx/var/repo/site.git    dea7aae..ad83be3  master -> master
```

The directory and the file exists so I dont really understand whats goin on, thank your for helpin me out.

Comment: Do you mean that `.git/hooks/post-receive` exists? It's not created by default. Is it a script you created? Is it invoked by some other script? What's in it?

Comment: @KeithThompson Yes it does exist, I created it: `#!/bin/bash
git --work-tree=/var/www/laravel --git-dir=/var/repo/site.git checkout -f`

Comment: Is this file on the server to which you are pushing? Hook files are not part of the repository.

Comment: What are the permissions on the file?

Comment: How is it invoked? I don't see any mention of `post-receive` in the git documentation. My guess is that some other script is invoking `hooks/post-receive` when its current directory is not `.git`, but we'll need more information to confirm or deny that. (If I include several questions in a comment, there's a reason for it. Please don't just answer the first and ignore the others.)

Comment: Make sure `/bin/bash` is the correct executable path and that there are no typos or other oddities in the `#!` line. A failure to exec an executable script occurs if the `#!` line isn't quite right. Shells themselves notice this and work around it, but programs like Git that just call the OS `exec` functions usually don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the file does exist on the remote side, is executable (chmod 755), then, [as seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26257188/6309), double-check the EOL.

It might have CRLF instead of LF: that would be enough to not make it executable.

Comment: I created the post-receive file on windows 10 and uploaded via ftp client, I tried to create it using nano on the server and the error now is: ```Enumerating objects: 11, done.
Counting objects: 100% (11/11), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (6/6), done.
Writing objects: 100% (6/6), 462 bytes | 462.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 6 (delta 5), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: fatal: this operation must be run in a work tree
To ssh://xx.xx.xx.xx/var/repo/site.git
   dea7aae..ad83be3  master -> master```

Comment: @MarekTesař First, it is possible that, created on Windows, it had CRLF instead of LF as end-of-lines characters. Second, could you edit your question with the content of your post-receive script?